# How to implement Paytm all in one sdk in react native giving error after adding AllInOneSDKSwiftWrapper.swift

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, flutter, paytm

I have created this AllInOneSDKSwiftWrapper.swift class then xcode asked me for bridging header I allowed it after adding code which is given in paytm [doc](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/all-in-one-sdk/hybrid-apps/react-native/) it is giving multiple errors in file. i have also added AllInOneSDKSwiftWrapper.m file. i am not ios developer so i don't know how to fix and what should i write in empty generated bridging header file.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to Paytm folks?

Comment: yes but no replay from there

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Paytm react native support documentation for both iOS and Android is very poor as it doesn't have the complete set of information required to setup and run the code in native end.

Below is the implementation for iOS running **Xcode v12.0**, **Swift 5**, **RN v0.63.2**

1. Download [AppInvokeSDK.framework](https://github.com/paytm/Paytm_iOS_All_in_One_SDK/tree/master/Swift/AppInvokeSDK.framework)
2. Copy and paste the framework inside "**ios/YourApp**" folder
3. Open your workspace and click on File -> Add Files
4. Navigate to the framework, select it and click on Add **(This is important, don't drag and drop as mentioned in the Paytm documentation)**
5. In **TARGETS/YourApp** under General tab, the framework should be linked in the section **Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content**
6. Change the Embed option to **Embed and Sign**
7. Add the below path link in **PROJECT -> YourApp -> Build settings**. Search for **Header Search Paths** and add the below path

   ***$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS***

Import headers in **Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"
```

**AllInOneSDKSwiftWrapper.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#if __has_include("RCTEventEmitter.h")
#import "RCTEventEmitter.h"
#else
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>
#endif

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(AllInOneSDKSwiftWrapper, RCTEventEmitter)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(openPaytm:(NSString *)mid
orderId:(NSString *)oid
transactionToken:(NSString *)txnTkn
amount:(NSString *)amt
callbackUrl:(NSString *)url
isStaging: (BOOL)isStaging)
@end
```

**AllInOneSDKSwiftWrapper.swift**

```
import Foundation
import AppInvokeSDK
import UIKit

class EventEmitter {
    /// Shared Instance.
    public static var sharedInstance = EventEmitter()

    // ReactNativeEventEmitter is instantiated by React Native with the bridge.
    private static var eventEmitter: AllInOneSDKSwiftWrapper!

    private init() {}

    // When React Native instantiates the emitter it is registered here.
    func registerEventEmitter(eventEmitter: AllInOneSDKSwiftWrapper) {
        EventEmitter.eventEmitter = eventEmitter
    }

    func dispatch(name: String, body: Any?) {
       EventEmitter.eventEmitter.sendEvent(withName: name, body: body)
    }

    /// All Events which must be support by React Native.
    lazy var allEvents: [String] = {
        var allEventNames: [String] = ["responseIfNotInstalled", "responseIfPaytmInstalled"]
        // Append all events here
        return allEventNames
    }()
}

@objc(AllInOneSDKSwiftWrapper)
class AllInOneSDKSwiftWrapper: RCTEventEmitter, AIDelegate {

    private let handler = AIHandler()

    var viewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController

    override static func moduleName() -> String! {
        return "AllInOneSDKSwiftWrapper"
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()

        EventEmitter.sharedInstance.registerEventEmitter(eventEmitter: self)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:   #selector(getAppInvokeResponse(notification:)), name:  NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "appInvokeNotification"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func getAppInvokeResponse(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            let url = userInfo["appInvokeNotificationKey"] as? String
            let response = self.separateDeeplinkParamsIn(url: url, byRemovingParams: nil)
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Response", message: response.description, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.viewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            sendEvent(withName: "responseIfPaytmInstalled", body: response)
        }
     }

     /// Base overide for RCTEventEmitter.
     ///
     /// - Returns: all supported events
     @objc open override func supportedEvents() -> [String] {
         return EventEmitter.sharedInstance.allEvents
     }

     @objc override static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
         return true
     }

     @objc(openPaytm:orderId:transactionToken:amount:callbackUrl:isStaging:)
     func openPaytm(_ mid: String, orderId: String, transactionToken: String, amount: String, callbackUrl: String?, isStaging: Bool) {
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             var env:AIEnvironment = .production
                 if isStaging {
                     env = .staging
                 } else {
                     env = .production
                 }
    
             self.handler.openPaytm(merchantId: mid, orderId: orderId, txnToken: transactionToken, amount: amount, callbackUrl: callbackUrl, delegate: self, environment: env)
          }
      }

      @objc func separateDeeplinkParamsIn(url: String?, byRemovingParams rparams: [String]?)  -> [String: String] {
          guard let url = url else {
              return [String : String]()
          }

          /// This url gets mutated until the end. The approach is working fine in current scenario. May need a revisit.
          var urlString = stringByRemovingDeeplinkSymbolsIn(url: url)
          var paramList = [String : String]()
          let pList = urlString.components(separatedBy:   CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "&?"))
          for keyvaluePair in pList {
              let info = keyvaluePair.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "="))
              if let fst = info.first , let lst = info.last, info.count == 2 {
                  paramList[fst] = lst.removingPercentEncoding
                  if let rparams = rparams, rparams.contains(info.first!) {
                      urlString = urlString.replacingOccurrences(of: keyvaluePair + "&", with: "")
                      
                      //Please dont interchage the order
                      urlString = urlString.replacingOccurrences(of: keyvaluePair, with: "")
                  }
               }
           }

           if let trimmedURL = pList.first {
               paramList["trimmedurl"] = trimmedURL
           }

           return paramList
       }

       func stringByRemovingDeeplinkSymbolsIn(url: String) -> String {
           var urlString = url.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: "&")
           
           // This may need a revisit. This is doing more than just removing the deeplink symbol.
           if let range = urlString.range(of: "&"), urlString.contains("?") == false {
               urlString = urlString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: "?")
           }

           return urlString
       }

       func openPaymentWebVC(_ controller: UIViewController?) {
           if let vc = controller {
               DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in self?.viewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)}
           }
       }

       func didFinish(with status: AIPaymentStatus, response: [String : Any]) {
           sendEvent(withName: "responseIfNotInstalled", body: response)
           let alert = UIAlertController(title: "(status)", message: String(describing: response), preferredStyle: .alert)
           alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
           DispatchQueue.main.async { self.viewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil) }
       }
 }
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "RCTLinkingManager.h" // Import this header

// Add the below function
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url
    options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{

    NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;
    NSDictionary *userInfo =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:urlString forKey:@"appInvokeNotificationKey"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"appInvokeNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
    return [RCTLinkingManager application:app openURL:url options:options];
}
```

**PaytmT.ts**

```
import { NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter, Alert } from 'react-native'

export class PaytmT {

    /** Call this function to invoke the Paytm Flow for iOS */
    invoke() {
        const allInOnePaytmSDK = NativeModules.AllInOneSDKSwiftWrapper
        allInOnePaytmSDK.openPaytm('MERCHANT_ID', 'ORDER_ID', 'TXN_TOKEN', 'AMOUNT', 'CALLBACKURL', true) // If production environment, change it to false

        const CounterEvents = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.AllInOneSDKSwiftWrapper)
        CounterEvents.addListener('responseIfNotInstalled', (response) => {
            Alert.alert(PaytmT.name, JSON.stringify(response))
        })
        CounterEvents.addListener('responseIfPaytmInstalled', (response) => {
            Alert.alert(PaytmT.name, JSON.stringify(response))
        })
    }
}
```